# I am getting error quoted in the body when I add new user and try adding claim in the next line

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'ConcurrencyStamp' on entity type 'AppUser' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.'*

a straight forward code is as below,

1. I am creating a new user.
2. For the same user, I try to add a claim.
3. I have added the IdentityUser class from asp.net core(3.1.2)

   ```
       var user = new AppUser() { UserName = userName, Email = emailAddress, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
       var passcode = GeneratePassword();
       var newUser = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, passcode);

       var addedClaim = await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("usertype", "admin"));

       internal class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, IRecord, IMPrimary {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   
        [Column("RecordCode")] 
        public Guid RecId { get; set; } 
        public override int Id { get; set; } 
        public string FirstName { get; set; } 
        public string LastName { get; set; } 
       } 

       (below is coming from vb.net coded class)

       Public Interface Record 
       Property RecId As Guid 
       End Interface 
       Public Interface IMPrimary 
       Property Id As Integer 
       End Interface
   ```

*IdentityUser in Asp.net core*

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1.
        public IdentityUser();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        //     The user name.
        public IdentityUser(string userName);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the date and time, in UTC, when any user lockout ends.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     A value in the past means the user is not locked out.
        public virtual DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if two factor authentication is enabled for this
        //     user.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their telephone address.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a telephone number for the user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store
        **public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }**
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A random value that must change whenever a users credentials change (password
        //     changed, login removed)
        public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a salted and hashed representation of the password for this user.
        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their email address.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the normalized email address for this user.
        public virtual string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the email address for this user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the normalized user name for this user.
        public virtual string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the user name for this user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the primary key for this user.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if the user could be locked out.
        public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the number of failed login attempts for the current user.
        public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the username for this user.
        public override string ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. So why is `ConcurrencyStamp` part of a key? We don't see how you configured `AppUser`.

Comment: Hi Arnold, Thanks for your response below is the user class. sorry for the ugly formation.


internal class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, IRecord, IMPrimary

    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("RecordCode")]
        public Guid RecId { get; set; }
        public override int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

Public Interface Record
        Property RecId As Guid
End Interface

Public Interface IMPrimary
        Property Id As Integer
End Interface

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: yeah, Sorry for the inconvenience, the code is already added into the question.

Comment: In fact, I didn't do anything special to inherit/extend this class and use it. But strange to get this error.

Comment: So where is `ConcurrencyStamp`?

Comment: This is coming from "IdentityUser<int>" itself. THE PARENT INHERITED CLASS

My point is I have never changed anything for this. So it comes with the default options from IdentityUser class of Asp.net core

Comment: I think you should do `userManager.AddClaimAsync(newUser...`,

Comment: This is what I am doing as in the code. I am creating new user and then I am adding a claim to it.

Comment: Yes, but you have `userManager.AddClaimAsync(user...`.

Comment: May be I am unable to understand your intention. newuser is the variable that I am creating and want to  assign the claims to. I have infact tried to add claim in a saperate call out of this context. I get the user from database and then wanted to assign it. Still it comes up with same error.

Comment: If I don't add claims to it it successfully creates the user and available in the database. The problem occurs when I add claim to this user later in a saperate session or the current one it comes up with this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of error so I thought of sharing it with you guys. I had an overridden OnModelCreating method. I mainly used it to set the maximum character length of string value columns. For some internal purpose logic, I was setting the key to these string base columns. So when it would come to IdentityUser columns they were also passing through the same pipe without my intention. **p.DeclaringEntityType.AddKey(p);** in below code was adding the key to **ConcurrencyStamp** also which was never expected by Identity System, so It threw the exception.

Thanks [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) for your efforts to help me out.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (modelBuilder == null)
                throw new NoNullAllowedException();
            var conventions = GetDbConventions();
            var props = GetPropertiesOfType(typeof(string));
            int maxCharacterLength = conventions.StringsColumnLength;
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                if (p.GetMaxLength() < maxCharacterLength)
                    p.SetMaxLength(maxCharacterLength);
                p.IsNullable = false;
                p.DeclaringEntityType.AddKey(p);
            };  
       }
```